# In Feistel block ciphers, does using a weak but iterated encryption function result in a cryptographically strong cipher?

Tags: block-cipher, feistel-network, blowfish

There is a Feistel block cipher based on Blowfish called Kaweichel.  In [one of its papers](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/144.pdf), there is this affirmation:

> For the construction of the round function one choses usually parallel
> substitutions (s-boxes). The output bits of these s-boxes are permuted
> in order to achieve diffusion. For the derivation of the round keys
> from the userkey one has to choose a key schedule.
>
> The basic idea behind this construction is that a weak, iterated
> encryption function will result in a cryptographically strong cipher.
> But there are minimum requirements for the round function
> (F-function). It should, for example, offer sufficient resistance
> against differential and linear cryptanalysis.
>
> [...]
>
> Rather than using a round key for the round function, the s-boxes are
> key dependant. This method got first widely known with the block
> cipher Blowfish. The advantage is, that differential and linear
> cryptanalysis are not applicable, since they require the knowledge of
> the s-boxes.

Is this affirmation true? Can one with little knowledge of ciphers design and build a strong cipher based on this?

Comment: There is also a 2006 paper where the author himself calls for more crypt-analysis after showing a minimal argument that some attacks are not possible. But I suppose this is more about the principle of using key-depend**e**nt S-boxes?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I think so. Also, you edited my question, I typed the exact text it was on that paper, the author is German and made small typos.

Comment: Yeah, well, dependant is an actual word, so he's excused :P

Comment: This might be an answer https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60502/what-are-the-requirements-from-a-round-function-in-feistel-network

Comment: This is dangerously on the opinion-based side, thus I make this a comment rather than an answer. The basic ingredients of a good classical block cipher are there: substitution, diffusion, rounds with derived keys. It's _possible_ to accidentally design a safe cipher from that, especially by using many rounds to compensate for the lack of analysis. Crude analogy: adding more concrete to a bridge design can help. Or not. So what? We want ciphers/bridges that are safe by design, and use resources (CPU/concrete) conservatively.